# Как прочесть JSON в Unity

Tags: json, unity3d

Помогите разобраться как прочесть JSON, именно SimpleJSON.cs http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON

```
Response = HttpUploadFile (apiURL, filePath, "file", "audio/wav; rate=44100");
        Debug.Log ("Response String: " +Response);
        var jsonresponse = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse(Response);
        if (jsonresponse != null) {     
            string resultString = jsonresponse ["result"] [0].ToString ();
            var jsonResults = SimpleJSON.JSON.Parse (resultString);
            transcripts = jsonResults ["alternative"] [0] ["transcript"].ToString ();
```

в логах получаю :

```
Response String: {"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"Green","confidence":0.68338615},{"transcript":"grill"},{"transcript":"Google"},{"transcript":"GN"},{"transcript":"grills"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}
```

Как мне считать/получить результаты, если json содержит Green, grill, Google, GN, grills, тогда допустим какие-то дальнейшие действия ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// список позволительных слов
List<String> allowedTranscript = new List<string> { "Green", "grill", "Google", "GN", "grills" };    
string transcript = "green";

if (allowedTranscript.Contains(transcript)) {
    // TODO
}
```

если надо без учета регистра, то

```
if (allowedTranscript.Contains(transcript, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    // TODO
}
```

---

№2

```
if (allowedTranscript.Any(s => s.Equals(transcript, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, когда явно присваиваю работает, но когда передаю полученное из JSON (в логах Debug.Log(transcripts); пишет "Green") а в списке пропускает, условие не срабатывает, что-то не правильно делаю?

Comment: List<String> allowedTranscript = new List<string> { "Green", "grill", "Google", "GN", "grills", "game", "moon", "Hello", "hello" };    
  //string transcript = "green";
  Debug.Log(transcripts);
   if (allowedTranscript.Contains(transcripts)) {
   Debug.Log ("TRANSCRIPT!");}

Comment: Тоесть при выводе transcripts получаю строку {"result":[]}
{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"Green","confidence":0.68338615},{"transcript":"grill"},{"transcript":"Google"},{"transcript":"GN"},{"transcript":"grills"}],"final":true}],"result_index":0}

Comment: @KostyaLikhachev это невалидный JSON..... может быть либо  `{"result":[]}`, либо `{"result":[{"alternative":[{"transcript":"Green","confidence‌​":0.68338615},{"tran‌​script":"grill"},{"t‌​ranscript":"Google"}‌​,{"transcript":"GN"}‌​,{"transcript":"gril‌​ls"}],"final":true}]‌​,"result_index":0}`